# Fadein on hover then fade out to orginal state but stay on hover state when onclicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I have to create is a fade in/out of an image to show the image behind it which has text on it, the user can stay on that button by clicking it. Then it will go back to its orginal state when an other button is clicked on. But while an image has been clicked on the other buttons can be hovered over.

There are 8 images/buttons.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a question. Have you tried anything yet or are you expecting us to give you a full working example here?

Comment: You need to go to IWantSomebodyDoMyTaskForFree.com

Comment: What you should do is try to find something close to what you want online. Then view the source to understand how it works.

Comment: I have actually tried alot of examples on the internet sorry I was hoping for a working example sort of thing I just don't get this jquery or javascript!! I do learn by doing so I'm trying to do a lot of tutorials but I'm just not getting it!! I can get it to hover into picture 2 but I can't get it to stay there while I hover over other images!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following classes to your CSS stylesheet:

1. A CSS class for the inactive button state:

   `.buttonInactive { /* your inactive styles here */ }`
2. A CSS class that makes use of the `:hover` pseudo-class that will automatically handle the hovering for you without JavaScript:

   `.buttonInactive:hover { /* your hover styles here */ }`
3. A CSS class that is for the currently-selected (i.e., most recently clicked button), which will be set via JavaScript:

   `.buttonActive { /* your active styles here */ }`

In your HTML each button should be set as `class="buttonInactive"`. If you test it at this point you should see the hovering working.

Then, in JavaScript, add a handler for clicking on the buttons:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".buttonInactive").click(function() {
      // your code here
   });
});
```

You've tagged your question with jQuery, which makes adding and removing styles very simple. Your JavaScript in the click handler will need to remove the `buttonActive` class from any other element that might have been active previously (can be done in one line of jQuery) and then add the `buttonActive` class to the clicked element (only takes one more line of jQuery). Optionally, you may want to remove `buttonInactive` from the currently active element (and, obviously, put it back when it becomes inactive).

The jQuery you need for this is very basic, so I'll leave it to you to do some googling and figure the rest out yourself.

Comment: EXCELLENT Thank you for your help!! I'll give this a go!! And let you know how I get on!